# Attempts to use an ajax call to the controller to insert search results into a table result in errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, hibernate, spring-mvc

Longer title would be:

"Attempts to use an ajax call to the controller to insert search results into a table result in errors while remaining on the same page results in "405" or "Direct self-reference leading to cycle... " errors"

---

I am trying to find a way to fill a table with search result while staying on same page using an ajax call to the controller.

ajaxCall->Controller->Service(completes search)->Controller(result from search)->back to ajax with response

I have an ajax call that is triggered on form submit after prevent default:

```
function ajaxGetSearchResults(link, form) {
    var myList=[];
    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
        "url" : link,
        "data" : form.serialize(),
        "dataType" : 'json',
        "type" : "POST",
        "headers": {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        "success" : function (response){
            console.log("Ajax success");
            fillTable(response);    
            console.log("Search results added to table: "+response);
        },
        "complete":  function(response){
            console.log("Ajax call to controller completed");

        },
        "error": function(){
            console.log("Ajax call to controller triggered error");
        }
    });
}
```

In the controller I recieve the ajax request as such:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ajaxScriptSearch", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody List<ResultViewDto> processAJAXRequestSearch(@RequestParam String a1, 
        @RequestParam String a2, @RequestParam String a3, @RequestParam String a4) {
        SearchDto searchDto = new SearchDto();
        searchDto.setAttribute1(a1);
        searchDto.setAttribute2(a2);
        searchDto.setAttribute3(a3);
        searchDto.setAttribute4(a4);
        try {
            /*
             calling Service, performing search using searchDto as a parameter, mapping result to resultViewDtos

            */
        } catch(Exception e){
            /* do something */
        }
        return resultViewDtos; 
}
```

The call to the service is successfull.
An example of resultViewDtos would be: [viewDto1, viewDto2, viewDto3] where every view dto contains a number of string values which need to be inserted into a table.

I seem to be getting a "HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported" error, but my ajax call is "type: POST".

When I tried doing it with GET insted, I get an "Direct self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain...)" error.

I am using jackson-core 2.6.2, jackson-databind 2.6.2, Spring 4, Hibernate 4.

---

I would appericiate any help I can get...

Comment: add the entire spring controller code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I managed to create a workaround for this.

I have changed my ajax call as such:

```
function ajaxGetSearchResults(link, form) {
    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
        "url" : link,
        "data" : form,
        "dataType" : 'json',
        "headers": {
            'Accept' : 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        "type" : "GET",
        "success" : function (response) {
            console.log("Ajax success");
            fillTable(response);
        },
        "complete":  function(response) {
            console.log("Ajax call to controller completed");

        },
        "error": function() {
            console.log("Ajax call to controller triggered error");
        }
    });
}
```

And my controller as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ajaxScriptSearch", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<String> processAJAXRequestSearch(@RequestParam String a1, 
    @RequestParam String a2, @RequestParam String a3, @RequestParam String a4) {
    SearchDto searchDto = new SearchDto();
    searchDto.setAttribute1(a1);
    searchDto.setAttribute2(a2);
    searchDto.setAttribute3(a3);
    searchDto.setAttribute4(a4);
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<ResultViewDto> resultViewDtos = new ArrayList<ResultViewDto>(); 
        try {
             /*
              calling Service, performing search using searchDto as a parameter, mapping result to resultViewDtos
             */
             for(int i=0; i<resultViewDtos.size(); i++){
               result.add(resultViewDtos.get(i).toResponseString()); //a new method
             }
        } catch(Exception e){
            /* do something */
        }
        return result;
}
```

toResponseString() is a new method I have created in my resultViewDto that returns a string in which the attributes I need are separated by ":".

After filling the result and sending it back to ajax as a response, I then split the recieved response first on (',') to get the individual "rows" equivalent to a single resultViewDto, and then by (':') to get the values for each cell.

There might be a better way of solving it, but this woked like a charm.
I hope this will be usefull for someone else too.